# How to use TimePickerDialog to DateTimePicker for EditText field correctly?

Tags: java, android, datetimepicker, timepicker

I'm unsure how to use `TimePickerDialog` to enable time selection along with `DatePickerDialog` so that the `editReturn_date` field gets a value of `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`.

I still don't understand what to do with this snippet to activate the time selection I added:

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
   @Override
   public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hours, int minutes) {

   }
};
```

And how to make the hour and minute values join the

```
month += 1; 
String return_date = String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d",day,month,year);
editReturn_date.setText(return_date);
```

- Code

```
        int day, month, year, hours, minutes;
        editReturn_date = findViewById(R.id.editReturn_date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        editReturn_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(RegisterLoean.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
                        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hours, int minutes) {
                                
                            }
                        };
                        month += 1;
                        String return_date = String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d",day,month,year);
                        editReturn_date.setText(return_date);
                    }
                },year,month,day);
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your issue is unclear, what is the exact problem you are facing ?

Comment: @Ben-J I've already changed the statement.

Answer (score 0):

**You** are incorrectly using `DatePickerDialog` and `TimePickerDialog`

**Defenition:**

- `DatePickerDialog` is used to let users select Date (Month, Day, Year)
- `TimePickerDialog` is used to let users select Time (Hour, Minutes)

**Thus** those two components are different from each other. However, you are treating/using them as if they are a single component.

**Solution**

1. Separate Date picking and Time picking. (ex. show `DatePickerDialog` first and show `TimePickerDialog` second)
2. Use a library that has BOTH Date and Time picking Dialog (sadly this is not provided by Android by default)

If you chose **option 2**, here are some libraries I recommend:

- [SingleDateAndTimePicker](https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker)
- [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)

These basically fulfill all your needs

- Both Date and Time ✅
- Time Localization ✅
- Date Time formatting ✅

Let me know if you have more questions. Thanks.